# rxjs publishReplay with conditional storage

Tags: javascript, rxjs, rxjs6

I have a hot observable that emits messages. Currently I'm using `publishReplay(1).refCount()` so everyone subscribing will receive the last message. Now, the messages passing through May have a field containing a boolean to determine if it should be just passed through to all subscribers, or if it should be stored in the replay to be emitted to all new sebscribers too.

Has anyone any idea, how to achieve this usecase?

Comment: don't quite understand the use case, could you explain more

Comment: Updated the description. I hope it helps.

Comment: so it's a case of whether it should be cached ? interesting

Comment: Yes, exactly. That's what I want to achieve.

Comment: isn't that straight forward logic, because multiple subscription on hot observable always get the same result. Need to rethink whether there's a better way to go about

Comment: Yeah, with publish and publishReplay all current subscribers get the same result, BUT with publishReplay(1), new subscribers also get the latest message. That behavior should be configurable in the message.

Comment: it is very tricky how to define new or old subscribers, because streams don't completed. Think you can consider setup two streams and put subscriber into groups

Answer (score 0):

I implemented my own `publishReplayConditionally` and `ConditionalReplaySubject`. They additionally accept an expression as a parameter to decide if the value should be stored.